# SUM of each row is counting null values as 0. How do I make mysql skip null values?

Tags: mysql, null, sum

Well, the values aren't null per say, they are in `VARCHAR(30)` but in decimal form. However some of the records have "NA" in some fields. I would like mysql to skip those rows in `SUM` calculation when "NA" is present in the fields used for the `SUM`. Mysql is treating all incalculable fields as 0. The 0 from fields containing "NA" is misleading. I am doing a `GROUP BY` `TABLE.ID`.

**Edit:**

> SELECT
>
> SUM(
>
> CASE
>   WHEN X >1 THEN 1
>
> WHEN X<-1 THEN 2
>   ELSE 3
>
> END
>
> CASE
>
> WHEN Y >1 THEN 1
>
> WHEN Y <-1 THEN 2
>
> ELSE 3

END)

> AS "Col X+Y";
>
> FROM TableA
>   GROUP BY TableA_ID;

Sometimes X and/or Y = "NA" on certain fields. I get 6 if both X and Y on TableA_ID = 17 or other numbers when one of them is "NA".

**Edit (quoting my comment on VARCHAR):**

> "I tried storing my values as DEC(5,2), but some of the data from Excel have NA's in the fields. I did set **X** DEC(5,2) NULL and tried inserting NA into it but kept getting an error (cannot be null). I also tried making the default value "NA" but still get an error (cannot be null). I'll add in a sample query as edit."

Comment: but if they are treated as 0, they won't be calculated anyway...

Comment: Why are you storing numbers in a `varchar(30)` and why are you storing `NA` instead of `NULL`?

Comment: Exactly as @fthiella says - this won't affect your result for a `SUM`, though for an `AVG` it would. If it's not too late I'd make this a `NUMERIC` column and use `NULL` instead of `NA`; that's pretty much how it's supposed to be done.

Comment: One does not "SUM rows", one "SUMS columns".  Please show an example of the query you are trying.

Comment: I tried storing my values as `DEC(5,2)`, but some of the data from Excel have NA's in the fields. I did set Col1 DEC(5,2) NULL and tried inserting NA into it but kept getting an error (cannot be null). I also tried making the default value "NA" but still get an error (cannot be null).

I'll add in a sample query as edit.

Comment: It sounds like your should be asking a different question, like "How to create a MySQL table from an Excel workbook".  I'd focus on getting the table created and populated correctly.

Comment: I know how to do it. However, I can't drop the "NA" values in the data; they are important. 0's is not an ideal substitute when `SUM` encounters the "NA" values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. I added in another WHERE clause using

> WHERE ..... AND(Colx IS NOT NULL OR Coly IS NOT NULL OR ......);

I switched back the values to DEC(3,1) and made the fields NULLable with defaults *null* if the field value is NULL. I had to understand how to use NULL. I took out the 'NA's in Excel and left those field values blank.

Answer (score 0):

if foo1 is null or NA just sum it as zero (the neutrum value in the addition), otherwise sum the value.

```
select sum( case when foo1  is null or foo1 = 'NA' then 0 else foo1 end) as sum, foo2
from FooTable group by foo2
```

or

```
select sum(foo1) from FooTable
where (foo2 <> 'NA' and foo2 is null) and (foo3 <> 'NA' or foo3 is null )
group by foo4
```

Comment: The problem is that there is a number value if the value is "NA". I'm querying a table on a lab test. NA means not recorded, IE: NA =/=0. It's not feasible to make an "NA?" BINARY on every field...

Comment: the problem is that you cannot explain yourself properly... try this new statement... if this does not help provide example real data, and what is supposed to happen (this is actually more important than know what are you doing)...